# Change an MDI Border Style in C#

Tags: c#, border, mdi

I was wondering how can I change the MDI Parent's Border Style?

[The Window has Fixed3D as it's default settings but I would like it to be just a normal border just like FixedSingle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27ezx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.